# Is it true that $\langle a+cb, a+cb\rangle = \langle a,a\rangle + c^2 \langle b,b\rangle $ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

We have $a=(a_1, \dots \dots , a_n)$ and $b=(b_1, \dots \dots , b_n) \quad$ so

$a+cb = (a_1+cb_1, \dots \dots , a_n+cb_n) \quad$ and $\langle a+cb, a+cb\rangle  = (a_1+ cb_1)^2 + \dots \dots + (a_n+cb_n)^2 $

Also $\langle a,a\rangle  = a_1^2 + \dots \dots + a_n^2 \quad$ and $\langle b,b\rangle  = b_1^2 + \dots \dots + b_n^2 \quad$ then

$\langle a,a\rangle  + c^2\langle b,b\rangle  = a_1^2+c^2b_1^2 + \dots \dots + a_n^2 + c^2b_n^2$

From above it is evident that RHS $\ne$ LHS. But my conclusion is not correct and I don't know where am I making mistake.

Comment: It's not true in general.  You need either $c = 0$ or $\langle a, b \rangle = 0$.

Comment: Please don't use $<$ and $>$ instead of $\langle$ and $\rangle$. The former are relations. They not only look wrong, they get the spacing of relation symbols. To get the latter, type `\langle` and `\rangle`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\langle a+cb,a+cb\rangle =\langle a,a\rangle +c\langle a,b\rangle +c\langle b,a\rangle +c^2\langle b,b\rangle =\langle a,a\rangle +2c\langle a,b\rangle +c^2\langle b,b\rangle$$

Thus,$\langle a+cb,a+cb\rangle =\langle a,a\rangle +c^2\langle b,b\rangle \Rightarrow c\langle a,b\rangle =0 \Rightarrow c=0$ or $\langle a,b\rangle=0$

Answer (score 0):

Since, a & b are vectors in n-dimensional space - R (real numbers), < a,b > can be defined as inner-product of a & b with standard norm in R.  Thus, when a & b are orthogonal, < a,b > = 0.  Thus, the equality holds good when c is not equal to zero.